# Is there a complete list of websites that can add a badge to a LinkedIn certificate?

Tags: linkedin

Consider:

[image]

I know Code School and [Coursera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coursera) can do it:

1. *[How do I add a badge to my LinkedIn profile?](http://codeschool.reamaze.com/kb/general/how-do-i-add-a-badge-to-my-linkedin-profile)*
2. *[Add Coursera accomplishments to your LinkedIn Profile](http://blog.coursera.org/post/66959529107/add-coursera-accomplishments-to-your-linkedin)*

Are there other websites/services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedIn's [Top 100 Certification Providers](https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/cert/ranking) (based on the number of certifications in profiles).